# about meeting space

Tags: windows-7

where is the windows meeting space

Answer (score 4):

Nowhere:

> Meeting Space does not exist in any version of Windows 7.

([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Meeting_Space))

Comment: +1, nice work getting a perfect answer in on a terrible question before the close hammer came down!